# Master and Details activity not work on some Tablets

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have made MasterActivity and DetailsActivity using Eclipse ADT and I tested it on my phone and tablet it works, But when I tested it with another tablet I faced this error

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.website.softarge/solutions.SolutionListActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
```

**My Code:**

```
   public class SolutionListActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
            SolutionListFragment.Callbacks {
    ...

// this line causes the error 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_solution_list);

    ...
    }
```

This code must call this Fragment

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/solution_list"
    android:name="solutions.SolutionListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    tools:context=".SolutionListActivity"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Android version of the tablet that fails. I think it is quite likely the tablet that is failing is a version prior to fragments existing (API Level 11, which was Android 3.0.x or Honeycomb). If that is the case you will want to use the Android support library which adds support for fragments in older android versions. My bet is you have a Gingerbread (2.3.x) or earlier tablet.

Comment: my android version is  4.1.1